# Convert multiple tuples to a single list in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have multiple tuples that I generate from a dict in the form of this:
The number is calculated based on the sum of a few variables, it's an integer, the strings in the tuple are the names of the documents.

```
    (4.3434, 'doc1')
    (139.324, 'doc2')
    (0, 'doc3')
```

What I want is:

```
    [(139.324, doc2), (4.3434, 'doc1'), (0, 'doc3')]
```

But how do I do this? A simple list comprehension like

```
    [x for x in tuples]
```

gives

```
    [(4.3434, 'doc1')]
    [(139.324, 'doc2')]
    [(0, 'doc3')]
```

Is it even possible to get it into a single list or should I somehow get it into a list of lists and try to sort that way? Thanks for any help

Comment: they are not integers at all

Comment: In your code what is tuples? a tuple of tuples?

Comment: Exactly how do you "have multiple tuples"? Please show us some self-contained code, perhaps simplified. In that "what I want" list, should `doc2` be in quotes? There is no way you could have gotten that last example in Python, since that is not a proper data structure. Please clean up your question.

Answer (score 1):

If your `tuples` variable is already a list of tuples, I'm afraid you already have what you look for.

if you feed tuples like `(1.23,'doc1')` into any python array it just takes the shape you look for.

```
tup_les=[]
tup_les.append((1.23,'doc1'))
tup_les.append((2.32,'doc2'))
tup_les.append((3.45,'doc3'))


>>> tup_les
>>> [(1.23, 'doc1'), (2.34, 'doc2'), (3.45, 'doc3')]
```

Otherwise you can edit your answer with better explanation of what you try to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Use `itertools.chain`:

```
import itertools
myList = itertools.chain(*tuples)
```

Example:

```
import itertools
tuples = [[(1,2,3)] for _ in xrange(10)]
tuples
[[(1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)]]
myList = list(itertools.chain(*tuples))
myList
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```